# In row table page break

Tags: tables, page-breaking, cals

I want to generate a report automatically. I use python to replace placeholders inside a LaTeX template. The report contains large complex tables that span multiple pages. I have found a packet `cals` https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.text.tex/gE80AAOQ83U that with a small modification supports inter row page breaks.

My problem now is that if the content of one cell spans more than two pages there will one page break but there should have been two. Any idea how to fix this?

Here is my example code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{cals}
\usepackage[latin]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\showboxbreadth=100
\showboxdepth=100

\makeatletter
\let\oldDispatch=\cals@row@dispatch
\newbox\rowBefore
\newbox\rowAfter
\newbox\decorationCopy
\newdimen\splitHeight

\def\cals@row@dispatch{%
\cals@ifbreak\iftrue % detect that a break is required
  \splitHeight=\pagegoal \advance\splitHeight -\pagetotal
  \ifdim \splitHeight>50pt % break inrow only if at least 100pt left
    \advance\splitHeight -5pt % avoid pagebreak due to overflows
    %
    % Split the current row on two: before and after the break
    %
    \setbox\rowBefore=\hbox{}
    \setbox\rowAfter=\hbox{}
    \def\next{%
      \setbox0=\lastbox
      \ifvoid0
        \def\next{\global\setbox\rowBefore=\box\rowBefore
                    \global\setbox\rowAfter=\box\rowAfter }%
      \else
        \setbox2=\vsplit0 to\splitHeight
        \ifvoid0
          \setbox0=\copy2
        \fi
        \setbox\rowBefore=\hbox{\box2 \unhbox\rowBefore}%
        \setbox\rowAfter=\hbox{\box0 \unhbox\rowAfter}%
      \fi
      \next}
    \setbox0=\hbox{\unhbox\cals@current@row \next}
    %
    % Decoration backup, typeset the first row,
    % restore context, typeset the second at the end of macro
    %
    \setbox\decorationCopy=\copy\cals@current@cs
    \setbox\cals@current@row=\box\rowBefore
    \ht\cals@current@cs=\ht\cals@current@row
    \oldDispatch
    \cals@issue@break
    \cals@thead@tokens
    \setbox\cals@current@row=\box\rowAfter
    \cals@reheight@cells\cals@current@row
    \setbox\cals@current@cs=\box\decorationCopy
    \ht\cals@current@cs=\ht\cals@current@row
    \let\cals@current@context=b
  \fi
\fi
\oldDispatch}

\begin{document}
\begin{calstable}
\colwidths{{150pt}{150pt}{150pt}}
\thead{\brow \bfseries \cell{header1}\cell{header2}\cell{header3} \mdseries \erow}

\brow \cell{foo} \cell{a2} \cell{b2} \erow
\brow \cell{foo} \cell{a2} \cell{b2} \erow
\brow \cell{foo} \cell{a2} \cell{b2} \erow
\brow \cell{foo} \cell{a2} \cell{b2} \erow
\brow \cell{foo} \cell{a2} \cell{b2} \erow
\brow \cell{foo} \cell{a2} \cell{b2} \erow
\brow \cell{foo} \cell{a2} \cell{b2} \erow
\brow \cell{foo} \cell{a2} \cell{b2} \erow
\brow \cell{foo} \cell{a2} \cell{b2} \erow
\brow \cell{foo} \cell{a2} \cell{b2} \erow
\brow \cell{foo} \cell{a2} \cell{b2} \erow
\brow \cell{foo} \cell{a2} \cell{b2} \erow
\brow \cell{foo} \cell{a2} \cell{b2} \erow
\brow \cell{foo} \cell{a2} \cell{b2} \erow
\brow \cell{foo} \cell{a2} \cell{b2} \erow
\brow \cell{foo} \cell{a2} \cell{b2} \erow
\brow \cell{foo} \cell{a2} \cell{b2} \erow
\brow \cell{foo} \cell{a2} \cell{b2} \erow
\brow \cell{foo} \cell{a2} \cell{b2} \erow
\brow \cell{foo} \cell{a2} \cell{b2} \erow
\brow \cell{foo} \cell{a2} \cell{b2} \erow
\brow \cell{foo} \cell{a2} \cell{b2} \erow
\brow \cell{\blindtext \blindtext \blindtext} \cell{foo3} \cell{foo3} \erow
\brow \cell{foo} \cell{a2} \cell{b2} \erow
\brow \cell{foo} \cell{a2} \cell{b2} \erow

\end{calstable}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! What about `longtable` package?

Comment: most tex multi-page codes don't easily allow page breaking mid-cell (it isn't in general possible to find breakpoints at matching positions in each column, consider having an image in one cell a nested table in another and a paragraph in the third, you would have to find a page break that cuts all three

Comment: @ChristianHupfer longtable won't help:-)

Comment: If, as in your example, there is just one column with the bulk data and the other columns all have small one line items, it is usually best to set it as a _list_ which naturally allows page breaking.

Comment: That wont work, because in the report all columns may have bulk data. In addition to that I have cells that span over multiple rows and others that span over multiple columns. I'm not aware that _list_ support that.

Comment: @user63843 I'm not aware of _anything_ that supports all your requirements, sorry..

Comment: You should take a look at the tasks package, that emulates a horizontal list environment, but also has an analog to multicolumn and \multirow.